# How can I Delete an external ID from a web

Tags: javascript, jquery, external

I'm working on [this page](http://www.mooysoft.com/mooytv/test.html),
and I'd like to delete those Pop Ups.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <iframe src ="http://tv-msn.com/action.html" width="485" height="405"></iframe>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#floatLayer').remove();
        $('#floatLayer3').remove();
        $('#floatLayer7').remove();
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried to use the click event but that was unsuccessful as well.

Any suggestions on how to make this work properly?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this... but you should look up how to edit DOMs in internal iframes.  It looks like it's several layers deep of iframes.

Comment: Since your iframe is loaded from a different domain, the script will not be able to access its DOM for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the help. im gonna try to edit the DOM,, maybe it could work idk.

Answer (score -2):

Yesterday I found the .js, and it looks like this. I just have to delete the `var arrU arr J`:

```
var arrU = 'mastertv';   
var arrJ = 'mastertv';        
var windowName = 'comercials';        
var urlPublicity = "(?:" + getName(arrU) + "|" + getName(arrJ) + "" + getName(arrU) + ")";        
var urlDC = "http://www." + getName(arrU) + ".biz";        
var urlDU = urlDC;        
var jaClicou = false;    
var wProps;        
var wOpen;        
var excludes = [];        
var u = "n.u.l.l";        
var cookieName = "dcPopunder";        
var cookie;        
var vlrCookie;        
var cookieDuration = 24 / 24;
```